# Joining rows into column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables that look like below that I want to join together so that the attribute table's rows become columns of the result table.

```
block
id  name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d

attr_value
id   value  block_id attr_type_id
1    0.1    1         1
2    0.2    1         2
3    0.3    2         3
4    0.4    3         4

attr_type
id   name
1    type_a
2    type_b
3    type_c
4    type_d


result table
block id  name   type_a  type_b  type_c  type_d 
1         a      0.1     0.2     null    null
2         b      null    null    0.3     null
3         c      null    null    null    0.4
4         d      null    null    null    null
```

I'm using postgresql and tried `case when` but this duplicated some columns (i.e. multiple block rows with id=1) which I didn't want.

Comment: Search for CROSSTAB queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  b.id,b.name
,(select a.value from attr_value a inner join attr_type at on at.id=a.attr_type_id where b.id=a.block_id and at.id=1) as 'type_a'
,(select a.value from attr_value a inner join attr_type at on at.id=a.attr_type_id where b.id=a.block_id and at.id=2) as 'type_b'
,(select a.value from attr_value a inner join attr_type at on at.id=a.attr_type_id where b.id=a.block_id and at.id=3) as 'type_c'
,(select a.value from attr_value a inner join attr_type at on at.id=a.attr_type_id where b.id=a.block_id and at.id=4) as 'type_d'
from block b
```

Comment: I didn't ask in the question, but is there a way to do this without knowing the IDs of the `attr_type` column a priori? Can this be done dynamically, i.e. whatever content is in `attr_type` will be added as column?

Comment: in attr_value table you are storing attr_type_id.
And in attr_vlalue there are multiple rows of block_id.
Now you can change your table structure.
you remove attr_type_id from attr_value table.
And create columns like type_a type_b... and put value there...
so your table should look like this...
id block_id type_a type_b type_c type_d
1 1  0.1 0.2 null null

Comment: I can't change the structure of the table. There needs to be a way to do this with a select query only...

Comment: one logic in my mind.. but 9 A.M to 8 P.M i am in office. and i need time so i can do it at my personal time and give you solution.
is there any deadline for this output ?

Comment: None that is more important than your own priorities, of course :-)

Comment: do you know sql server ?? and is it install in your computer ??

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result_table
(
    blockid bigint,
    name varchar(10),
    type_a float default 1,
    type_b float default 2,
    type_c float default 3,
    type_d float default 4
)

insert into result_table(blockid,name)select id,name from block

update result_table
set type_a=(select value from attr_values a where a.block_id=blockid and a.attr_type_id=type_a)
,type_b=(select value from attr_values a where a.block_id=blockid and a.attr_type_id=type_b)
,type_c=(select value from attr_values a where a.block_id=blockid and a.attr_type_id=type_c)
,type_d=(select value from attr_values a where a.block_id=blockid and a.attr_type_id=type_d)


select * from result_table

drop table result_table
```

Comment: try this,, as you told dynamic.
i have created in sql server and convert it in postgresql. i hop it work

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. The problem is that `type_a..d` are not known at time of writing the query, that is, there could be a `type_e` or anything, so a query containing hard-coded ids or column names for attr_type would not work. I might have a look at pivot tables and see how I can use them... Thanks anyway.